# Permission denied for object sysmonitors [Sybase]

Tags: sap-ase, permission-denied

I got permission denied problem which executing query for Sybase.

**1. Exception: SELECT permission denied on object sysmonitors, database master, owner dbo.**

**2. Exception: master.dbo.monCachePool not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the objects persist(sp_help may produce lots of product).**

My database is sybasedb and my username is tester, not sa. For super user 'sa' is okay, no exception. But when I created normal user and tested it, I got these exceptions. I thought that this is permission issue. That's why I grant permission for this user 'test' to be able to access these tables. Like this:

- grant select on master.dbo.monCachePool, master.dbo.monDataCache to tester

But still can not. I got above exceptions. Please help me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you have not granted the correct role to your test user.  You must add `mon_role` to your user to access the monitoring tables.

```
grant role mon_role to *username*
```

or

```
sp_role 'grant', mon_role, *username*
```

More information can be found in the [Performance and Tuning Series: Monitoring Tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00848.1570/html/monitor_tables/CIHDJABI.htm)